# Как посчитать количество комбинаций текста на русском языке длиной 1000 символов?

Tags: математика, информатика

В русском языке 400 000 слов.
Средняя длина слова в русском языке 5,28 символа.
Смысловое содержание текста значения не имеет, интересует лишь максимальное количество комбинаций.

Каким образом оценить количество возможных текстов длиной в 1000 символов?

Comment: из имеющихся данных ответ нельзя получить. Т.к. ответ 34 ^ 1000 не противоречит ничему. Если вы хотите количество РЕАЛЬНЫХ текстов то задача значительно сложнее и требует формальной грамматики языка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простое решение на Си: заполнение текста словами и умножение на количество вариантов, то есть, слов в алфавите. В результате получается **гигантское** число, никуда не помещается, поэтому храню только степень: 400000 ^ 190. Если добавить пробелов между словами, но степень на 30 меньше.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int wordsCount = 400000;
const double wordLength = 5.28;
const int textLength = 1000;

int main () {
    // количество символов в тексте
    double symbolCount = 0;
    // степень количества вариантов
    unsigned int power = 1;
    // заполнение текста словами
    while (symbolCount < textLength) {
        symbolCount += wordLength;// + 1 для пробелов
        power++;
    }
    // цикл заполняет текст больше лимита, можно вычесть одно словечко
    power--;
    // собственно, вывод результатов
    printf("%d ^ %u\n", wordsCount, power);
    return 0;
}
```

---

А Питон посчитал и так:

```
wordsCount = 400000
wordLength = 5.28
textLength = 1000

count = 1
symbols = 0

while (symbols < textLength):
    count *= wordsCount
    symbols += wordLength + 1

count
```

Но результат не внушает доверия, нулей у него совсем недостаёт:

> 213598703592091008239502170616955211460270452235665276994704160782221972578064055002296208693657600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: А разве не 190^400000?

Comment: Нет! Основы комбинаторики. Простой пример: два друга делят случайным образов конфеты. Сколько вариантов результата есть? 8, 2^3, количество вариантов в степени количества случаев.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.

Comment: Если проблема просто получить число, то можно взять калькулятор :) - 40000^190 = 2,462625E874... Все равно это очень грубая оценка, потому что слова нельзя считать равновероятными в любом случае, безотносительно к смыслу - если попадутся подлиннее, их будет меньше, а покороче - больше 190. Так что тут даже самому порядку - 874 - можно верить лишь как оценочной величине...